# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values While navigating website

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

In the following code, I have a page loading.  Once it finishes loading, I log into the site.  Once the log on is complete and the next page loads, I need to click on a link.

The problem is that the link tries to click before the page following the log in finishes loading.

The error I get is: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index

```
    int linkcount = 0;

    public PNow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https:...com/login.aspx");
    }

    private void PNow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        linkcount++;

        if (linkcount == 1)
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Login1_UserName").SetAttribute("value", "username");
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Login1_Password").SetAttribute("value", "password");
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Login1_LoginButton").InvokeMember("click");
        }

        if (linkcount == 2)
        {
            HtmlElement link = (from HtmlElement elem in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
            where elem.GetAttribute("title") == "Time Clock Entry"
            select elem).ElementAt(0);
        }
    }
```

I have tried using a Thread.Sleep(5000); but that just stops the entire program and the issue is still there.

Thank you.

The markup for the section of the page that contains the link is as follows...

```
<ul>
<li id="menuLi_2708"><a  class="noTimer container-menu" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showFirstChildMenu(this)">Career Development</a><ul>
<li id="menuLi_2708"><a  href="#" class="page-link" onclick="showMenu('pages/EDIT/CDAvailableDevOppSummary.aspx?USParams=PK=ESS!MenuID=2708!PageRerId=2711!ParentRerId=2708','72','2708','2711', false, false, this.innerHTML, true);" data-RerID='2711'>Available</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li id="menuLi_2708"><a  href="#" class="page-link" onclick="showMenu('pages/EDIT/CDCurrentDevOppSummary.aspx?USParams=PK=ESS!MenuID=2708!PageRerId=2732!ParentRerId=2708','72','2708','2732', false, false, this.innerHTML, true);" data-RerID='2732'>Current</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li id="menuLi_2708"><a  href="#" class="page-link" onclick="showMenu('pages/EDIT/CDCompletedDevOppSummary.aspx?USParams=PK=ESS!MenuID=2708!PageRerId=2735!ParentRerId=2708','72','2708','2735', false, false, this.innerHTML, true);" data-RerID='2735'>Completed</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li id="menuLi_2148"><a  href="#" class="page-link" onclick="showMenu('pages/VIEW/UTMSSO.aspx?USParams=PK=ESS!MenuID=2148!PageRerId=2148!ParentRerId=72','72','2148','2148', false, false, this.innerHTML, true);" data-RerID='2148'>Time Management</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li id="menuLi_2147"><a  href="#" class="page-link" onclick="showMenu('pages/VIEW/UTMEntry.aspx?USParams=PK=ESS!MenuID=2147!PageRerId=2147!ParentRerId=72','72','2147','2147', false, false, this.innerHTML, true);" data-RerID='2147'>Time Clock Entry</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li id="menuLi_95"><a  class="noTimer container-menu" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showFirstChildMenu(this)">Pay</a><ul>
<li id="menuLi_95"><a  href="#" class="page-link" onclick="showMenu('pages/VIEW/EePayrollPayCheckDetail.aspx?USParams=PK=ESS!MenuID=95!PageRerId=1417!ParentRerId=95','72','95','1417', false, false, this.innerHTML, true);" data-RerID='1417'>Current Pay Statement</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li id="menuLi_95"><a  href="#" class="page-link" onclick="showMenu('pages/VIEW/EePayrollPayCheckHistory.aspx?USParams=PK=ESS!MenuID=95!PageRerId=18!ParentRerId=95','72','95','18', false, false, this.innerHTML, true);" data-RerID='18'>Pay History</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li id="menuLi_95"><a  href="#" class="page-link" onclick="showMenu('pages/VIEW/EePayrollYTDSummary.aspx?USParams=PK=ESS!MenuID=95!PageRerId=20!ParentRerId=95','72','95','20', false, false, this.innerHTML, true);" data-RerID='20'>YTD Summary</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li id="menuLi_95"><a  href="#" class="page-link" onclick="showMenu('pages/VIEW/WPRThirdPartyPayHistory.aspx?USParams=PK=ESS!MenuID=95!PageRerId=3561!ParentRerId=95','72','95','3561', false, false, this.innerHTML, true);" data-RerID='3561'>Third Party Pay</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block looks highly suspicious to me:

```
if (linkcount == 2)
{
    HtmlElement link = (from HtmlElement elem in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
    where elem.GetAttribute("title") == "Time Clock Entry"
    select elem).ElementAt(0);
}
```

It would seem that you have no elements with an attribute named title which, after invoking ToString() on them, evaluate to "Time Clock Entry". As a result, the sequence contains zero elements, which causes an ArgumentOutOfRangeException to be thrown.

I'd closely examine this block, and step through it very carefully. Set some watches in the debugger. Use the Immediate Window. Closely scrutinize what you see there. More than likely, you aren't pulling back what you think you are.

**UPDATE**

This is your hyperlink:

```
<a href="#" 
    class="page-link" 
    onclick="showMenu('pages/VIEW/UTMEntry.aspx?USParams=PK=ESS!MenuID=2147!PageRerId=2147!ParentRerId=72','72','2147','2147', false, false, this.innerHTML, true);" 
    data-RerID='2147'>
    Time Clock Entry
</a>
```

Note that you do not have an *attribute* that evaluates to "Time Clock Entry". Instead, the element's **InnerHtml** or **InnerText** property evaluates to "Time Clock Entry".

Change your code as follows:

```
if (linkcount == 2)
{
    HtmlElement link = (from HtmlElement elem in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
    where elem.InnerHtml == "Time Clock Entry"
    select elem).ElementAt(0);
}
```

That should get you going.

Comment: The code for the link I need to click is as follows: <a href="#" onclick="recentlyVisitedSelect('pages/VIEW/UTMEntry.aspx?USParams=PK=ESS!MenuID=2147!PageRerId=2147!ParentRerId=72','72','2147','2147', false, false, 'Time Clock Entry', true)" title="Time Clock Entry">Time Clock Entry</a>  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @SeanConnelly Can you provide the markup in the question for us?

Comment: My brain is not working well right now...  If you are asking for the HTML for the page I am looking at, that is a little over 1200 lines.  Or would a smaller segment from that section of the page work?

Comment: @SeanConnelly At 1200 lines, I think you can just post the relevant hyperlink. :) I'm still suspicious of the LINQ query, tho. Try changing .Element(0) to .FirstOrDefault() and see what comes back.

Comment: The change you suggested did in fact prevent the error, so we are moving in the right direction.  The link does not click though.  I hav added the markup to the question.

Comment: AWESOME!  That was it!  I have been working on this off an on for two weeks.  THANK YOU!